# IE: Object doesn't support property or method 'closest'

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, mootools

I am getting "Object doesn't support property or method 'closest'" error in IE. I am using MooTools. Can anyone help me..

```
var li = $$('.list')[0].clone(true, true);

var NewContainer = li.getElement('div.tile');

NewContainer.removeProperty('style');

NewContainer.set('id', 'container_'+catId);

NewContainer.closest('li').set('id', 'list_'+countID);
```

Comment: What does this method`li.getElement('div.tile')` returns?

Comment: @user2181397: It returns html div element with the class'tile'

Comment: T.J. Crowder: You are right. I am using MooTools .

Comment: @Andreas: Only in devtools, not generally: https://jsfiddle.net/7oquk42e/ Chrome does too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MooTools doesn't have `closest`. You may have wanted [`getParent`](http://mootools.net/core/docs/1.6.0/Element/Element#Element:getParent) (which accepts a selector for finding an ancestor), but unlike jQuery's `closest` it doesn't look at the current element (I don't think that's an issue here).

But note that you *already* have a reference to the `li` parent of `NewContainer` in the variable `li`.